# MariaDB query row to column with unique filter

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot, row, multiple-columns

I am trying to convert some rows to columns in a single table and can't get it work. :(

Here is my simple MariaDB table called **runningtimes**:

[image]

So I have tried various methods including pivot or aggregation but I always get errors or not the desired ouput.

What I am looking for is something like:

[image]

The column headers should contain the row values and the final reslut should have a filter that only shows the fastest time per runner.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which make and version of RDBMS do you use? Please [edit] your tags. Doing this without a common table expression or two is going to be really unpleasant.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks. It's a simple MariaDB on a webserver.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry, bit of a noob :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post what errors your are getting or the sample of the code that you have tried till now, I can only assume that you must be facing issues with the special characters in your column name.

I can help you with pivoting the table. In your case you need to use (`) back quote with your column names.

So the pivot table code will look like this:

```
Select 
  entry_id,
  (case when meta_key = "name-1" then meta_value end) as `name-1`,
  max(case when meta_key = "name-2" then meta_value end) as `name-2`,
  max(case when meta_key = "select-1" then meta_value end) as `select-1`,
  max(case when meta_key = "select-2" then meta_value end) as `select-2`,
  min(case when meta_key = "text-1" then meta_value end) as `text-1`
  
from runningtimes
group by entry_id , "name-1", "text-1"
```

Then in the select statement use where clause to filter data only from London:

```
Select * from runningtimes_Pivot where `select-2` = "London"
```

Code with filter data: https://dbfiddle.uk/cOn9XHyA

Edited answer based on your comment:

```
Select 
  entry_id,
  `name-1`,
  `name-2`,
  `select-1`,
  `select-2`,
   `text-1`
from
(
Select 
  entry_id,
  (case when meta_key = "name-1" then meta_value end) as `name-1`,
  max(case when meta_key = "name-2" then meta_value end) as `name-2`,
  max(case when meta_key = "select-1" then meta_value end) as `select-1`,
  max(case when meta_key = "select-2" then meta_value end) as `select-2`,
  min(case when meta_key = "text-1" then meta_value end) as `text-1`
from runningtimes
group by entry_id , "name-1", "text-1"
)ref1
group by `name-1`
```

Comment: That's good stuff!! How can I add a filter that will show only results from London and only the fastest time? Sorry, bit of an query noob.

Comment: @OpperSnokker, you can use where clause to fetch data for only "London" and the fastest time can be fetched by using Min() function when you write your select statement.

Comment: @OpperSnokker, look at my answer with the edit code. It will now fetch the data only for London and fastest time per name.

Comment: @OpperSnokker, did the solution work for you?

Comment: Hello @Jiji not completely. when i change the users to unique id's it will not work.

Please see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/66AZoVTL

Comment: Problem is, I need to execute this query on a wordpress table so I am not allowed to use insert or create table ... :(

Can I use this with a temportary table in memory? Just trying to work around some wordpress shortcomings.

Comment: @OpperSnokker, so you are saying that in your table you will have same user associated with multiple unique IDs??

Comment: @OpperSnokker, check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/VYPqvSVa. This should solve your issue. Also, you can create temporary table or work directly on the table that you have in your wordpress.

Comment: just remove "max()" function from entry-id. So that you can get the correct one. Look here: https://dbfiddle.uk/78ce_DWT

Comment: these id's are form entries, and each user can have multiple form entries indeed. I will have a look at a temporary table since I am not allowed any command except select. Thanks!

Comment: just checked, wordpress does also not allow temp tables :(

Comment: So, the following fiddle shows almost the exact result. I found a different way to filter for the location so that's not needed anymore. The only thing that is missing is to show only the fastest time per enrty. 

https://dbfiddle.uk/Vzfxrg06

Comment: @OpperSnokker, it's simple. Then you just need to write a subquery as you require two groups here. Look at the edited answer or the db fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/a3pGIwdG

Comment: thanks a lot! I was able to add the sorting of the fastest time and seperate wet times. Does this look ok to you? https://dbfiddle.uk/oIWFciKA

Comment: @OpperSnokker, yes that's correct! Glad that I was able to help you in solving your issue. If you have achieved what you wanted, then could you please accept the answer :)